# PostgreSQL Error: Relation already exists - FOREIGN KEY in CREATE TABLE

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, namespaces

I am making a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE creator.lists
(
    _id bigserial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    account_id bigint NOT NULL,
    created timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    display_name text DEFAULT '',
    name text DEFAULT '',
    extra jsonb,

    FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
        REFERENCES creator.accounts (_id)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

but I get this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "account_id_index" already exists
```

When I run:

```
CREATE INDEX
    account_id_index
ON
    creator.lists
(
    account_id
);
```

How do I create an index on the foreign key? I am running v11.1

**Just a note**, that I've also ran a similar command before for another table:

```
CREATE INDEX
    account_id_index
ON
    creator.contacts
    (
        account_id
    );
```

I don't suppose that index names need to be unique between tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indexes live in the same namespace as tables, views and sequences, so you cannot use the same name twice for any of these objects in one schema.

Either choose a different name, or have PostgreSQL choose one for you:

```
CREATE INDEX ON creator.lists (account_id);
```

Comment: I've decided to let psql do it for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it seems like index names need to be unique as removing the naming fixed it:

```
CREATE INDEX
ON
    creator.contacts
    (
        account_id
    );
```

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html):

> `name`
> The name of the index to be created. No schema name can be included here; the index is always created in the same schema as its parent table. If the name is omitted, PostgreSQL chooses a suitable name based on the parent table's name and the indexed column name(s).